# Chung's A Course in Probability Theory, exercise 3.1.3

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Can you solve exercise 3.1.3 from Chung's A Course in Probability Theory?

It is to show that:
Given any p.m.(probability distribution measure) $\mu$ on $(\Bbb R^1, \Bbb B^1)$, define an
r.v. (random variable) whose p.m. is $\mu$. Can this done be in an arbitrary probability space?

If we let the probability space same as $(\Bbb R^1, \Bbb B^1, \mu)$ and just let r.v. X to be an identical function, then its p.m. must be $\mu$.

How about it is an arbitrary probability space, namely $(\Omega, \Bbb F, \Bbb P)$ ? Can we find the legit r.v. X for that?

Comment: As an extreme case, what if $\Omega=\{1\}$ and $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$?

Comment: I got it.. so it is false in an arbitrary space?

Comment: Indeed, the probability space must be "large enough" in order to realize any probability distribution.